# Index Placement Conventions in Group Theory

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

In his book on group theory, Wu-Ki Tung seems to utilize a few peculiar conventions regarding the placement of indices on vector and matrix symbols. For instance, if $|x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n|e_i\rangle x^i$ and $|y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n|e_i\rangle y^i$, he writes: $$\langle x|y\rangle=\sum_i x^\dagger_{\phantom{\dagger}i}y^i= x^\dagger_{\phantom{\dagger}i}y^i$$ where apparently $$x^\dagger_{\phantom{\dagger}i}=x^{i*}.$$ I assume that with the symbol $x^\dagger_{\phantom{\dagger}i}$ Tung means the $i$-th entry of the conjugate transpose of the column matrix representing $|x\rangle$ in the $|e_i\rangle$ basis, since there is no such thing as the conjugate transpose of a vector itself. Furthermore I think Tung places the $i$ downstairs in $x^\dagger_{\phantom{\dagger}i}$ simply in order for the above expression for the inner product to be in accord with the summation convention. Please do correct me if I’m wrong.

Later on he writes $A^{\text{T}\phantom{i}j}_{\phantom{\text{T}}i}=A^i_{\phantom{i}j}$ for the elements of the transpose of a matrix $A$ and $$A^{\dagger i}_{\phantom{\dagger i}j}=A^{*\phantom{j}i}_{\phantom{*}j}=\left(A^j_{\phantom{j}i}\right)^*$$ for the elements of the complex conjugate of a matrix. I have no clue why he does this, so I’d appreciate some help.